# How to work with DOMDocumentFragment in a XSLT with registerPHPFunctions?

Tags: php, dom, xslt

See sections *"it works"* and *"it NOT works"*: **is a bug of my code or a bug of DOMDocument-PHP implementation?**

---

If you not familiar with XSLT and *registerPHPFunctions* see [this link for context and preparations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions#XSL_receiving_external_XML_as_DOMElement). Suppose input by strings,

```php
 function XSL_transf($xml,$xsl) {
         $xmldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
         $xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);
         $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
         $proc->registerPHPFunctions();  // here
         $proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
         echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
 }
 $xml='<root/>'; //simplest
 $xsl = <<<'EOB'
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
       ... HERE COPY/PASTE YOUR XSLT template ...
 </xsl:stylesheet>
 EOB;
```

### it works

The clause `<xsl:copy-of ... />` receives *DOMElement*, *DOMDocument* and (why not?) *DOMDocumentFragment*.
So, if we have a PHP function that returns DOMDocument, we can use it.

```
function foo1() {
    $dom = DOMDocument::loadXML('<t> foo <tt val="123"/> bar </t>');
    return $dom; 
}
```

Calling `foo1` into the template,

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   PHP foo1()=<xsl:copy-of select="php:function('foo1')" />
</xsl:template>
```

RESULTS (you can use `XSL_transf($xml,$xsl)` to see):

```
 <t> foo <tt val="123"/> bar </t>
```

### it NOT works

Changing the function above by

```
function foo1() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $tmp = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $tmp->appendXML('<t> foo <tt val="123"/> bar </t> test'); 
    return $tmp;
}
```

the RESULT is empty. No error messages, but no result.

Comment: I went to the link and tried to read through, but it seems to be very poorly worded. I hope someone else out here can give you a heads up on it

Comment: Ok, I edited, perhaps now the  explanation is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve using the following XPath expression:

```
php:function('foo1')/node()
```

Now, is it a PHP bug? Or a libxml2 bug? It's difficult to say, because if you look at the [specifications of XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath), you cannot find any reference to document fragments. The most similar thing is the *[root node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model)*, which is also the node used to represent a document.

I think the problem comes from PHP, [when it constructs the node set to be returned](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/xsl/xsltprocessor.c#L356). It should not return the whole document fragment node, but return a *nodeset* which is formed by its content.

However, I could be completely wrong, since I never used libxml2 and I don't know how it does work.

Comment: Yes, the `/node` was a good workaround!! I am testing another things, but it seems the solution!

Comment: Thanks, I am using your solution [here in a Wikibook about XSL/registerPHPFunctions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions#XSL_receiving_external_fragments).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a documentation about what data can be returned from an function called via registerPHPFunctions(). In doubt you have to check the source of libxml2 / libxslt (http://xmlsoft.org/).

Maybe the reason your second example doesn't work is that it doesn't contain valid xml in terms of having a single root element. The word "test" at the end is an text node at the same level as the element <t> before. Test to either cut of the text node or wrap a root node around. A DocumentFragment includes multiple elements, but that seems not to be returned properly.

If the second example does not work that way, returning DocumentFragments might not be supported at all.

@Peter Krauss: Not sending error messages is a common behavior of xml when it comes to empty node sets. I use libxslt function myself, but sent plain text only yet. When I tried sending arrays I failed. Maybe for you it is a way to only use text and convert it into a nodeset on the xslt side?

Comment: About documentation: I was looking for, but I not see. If you point the link, we will  see. About the second example: no, I need fragment to do just that (otherwise would have a solution), and if you test with a "well formed root", the result will be the same.  About "not support", is possible, but "no error messages" produced my hope.